# Local minima of a function defined using special functions.

Tags: functions, special-functions, maxima-minima

A function is defined as $$f(x)=[x](x^2-25)^n((x^2+3)(x^2+3x+4)^3)^m, m,n\in \mathbb N$$

Where [$x$] represents the the function defined as [$x$]="the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$".

Its also known that $f(x)$ attains minimum value at $x=5$. We have to find the value of $m$ and $n$ with this information.

I tried differentiating and putting the value of $x=5$, but all terms becomes zero. This was a multiple choice question and the options were:

A) $m=10,n=5$ B)$m=5,n=10$

C)$m=20,n=5$ D)$m=10,n=3$

I cannot find any method to solve this question and even taking the first and second derivative at $x=5$ takes much time, while the average time allotted per question is about two minutes.

Comment: is the function $R \to R$?

Comment: Yes. it is must be $R \rightarrow R$, as they have'nt specially mentioned anything, we are supposed to assume it that way.

Comment: that is not possible, because $f(5)=0$ so, you should have $f(x)\ge 0$ what is not possible if you take for example $x=-6$, $(f(-6)<0)$.

Comment: Hmm. They normally intend the functions to be defined on reals. Is a solution possible if $f$ is defined on some other domain and range?

Comment: Also the answer is given as option B.

Comment: I think there is some problem with the statement. See that $((x^2+3)(x^2+3x+4))^m>0$ for every $x$. So, if we are looking for $f(x)\ge 0$ the value of $m$ doesn't matter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58658/discussion-between-ananth-kamath-and-arnaldo).